# Stop navigator.notification.beep(100);

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I've a cordova app with a beep notification:

```
navigator.notification.beep(100);
```

It works well, but I want the user to be able to stop the device from beeping.

How do I remove the notification or stop the device from beeping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you give this a try? While an user in your app you could make use of setInterval and play the beep-noise once every 5 seconds:

```
var stop = false;
...
...
var inter = setInterval(function(){

   if(!stop)navigator.notification.beep(1);
   else clearInterval(inter);

},5000);
...
function stopBeepNoise(){ stop = true; }
```

The delay of the interval should correspond to the length of the beep-noise. For **android** the length of the beep-noise approximately takes 5 seconds because of
what I can see within the source-code of this [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/blob/master/src/android/Notification.java) is that 5 seconds(*long timeout*) have to pass so that a timeout has ended while the program is an loop **and**/**or** the length of noise is reached so that *isPlaying* returns *false* so you can not absolutely be sure that after 5 seconds a beep-noise has ended it might be less than 5 seconds:

```
for (long i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      notification.play();
      long timeout = 5000;
      while (notification.isPlaying() && (timeout > 0)) {
           timeout = timeout - 100;
           try {
               Thread.sleep(100);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           }
      }
}
```

of course for ios it looks different but here I would suggest to test the adjusted delay in real situations on a ios/winphone/-device.

*stopBeepNoise* could be called by touching a button and so stopping the interval.